# Read Only field not displaying information

Tags: javascript, woocommerce

We have an ecommerce website where we can't allow the users to edit their shipping address, but would like them to able to store multiple addresses from a drop down.  I used the following code to make the shipping address read only and not editable, but when they select a different address from the drop down the readonly fields do not update.  I tried the disabled attribute which worked visually, but we need the data to POST when placing an order.  Is there any work around for this?

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
  $("#shipping_last_name").attr("readonly", true);
});
```

Comment: What do you plan on doing if the user opens devtools and manually removes readonly? The frontend can always be manipulated, so if you don't want the user to manipulate the values, your best choice is to give each alternative an ID and only send that ID to the backend. Then you extrapolate the address from that ID.

Comment: What's your code to update the readonly input's value with the dropdown selection?

Comment: Appreciate the response!  It is a plugin called woocommerce address book.  It adds the ability to store multiple woocommerce shipping addresses and retrieve them at checkout.  We are a small business where customers are approved individually and addresses are changed and synced through our accounting software.  The addresses need to match up, I am not too concerned about our customers playing around in dev tools it will just cause an error if their address does not match our accounting software.  I am going to drill down into the address book code and see how that pulls in from the database.

Answer (score 0):

/**
* Adds the address book select to the checkout page.
*
* @since 1.0.0
*
* @param array $fields An array of WooCommerce Shipping Address fields.
* @return array
*/
public function shipping_address_select_field( $fields ) {
if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
$address_book = $this->get_address_book();

```
        $address_selector['address_book'] = array(
            'type'     => 'select',
            'class'    => array( 'form-row-wide', 'address_book' ),
            'label'    => __( 'Address Book', 'woo-address-book' ),
            'order'    => -1,
            'priority' => -1,
        );

        if ( ! empty( $address_book ) && false !== $address_book ) {
            foreach ( $address_book as $name => $address ) {
                if ( ! empty( $address[ $name . '_address_1' ] ) ) {
                    $address_selector['address_book']['options'][ $name ] = $this->address_select_label( $address, $name );
                }
            }

            $address_selector['address_book']['options']['add_new'] = __( 'Add New Address', 'woo-address-book' );

            $fields['shipping'] = $address_selector + $fields['shipping'];
            $fields['shipping']['custom_attributes'] = array('readonly'=>'readonly');
        }
    }

    return $fields;
}

/**
 * Adds the address book select to the checkout page.
 *
 * @since 1.0.0
 *
 * @param array  $address An array of WooCommerce Shipping Address data.
 * @param string $name Name of the address field to use.
 * @return string
 */
public function address_select_label( $address, $name ) {
    $label = '';

    $address_nickname = get_user_meta( get_current_user_id(), $name . '_address_nickname', true );
    if ( $address_nickname ) {
        $label .= $address_nickname . ': ';
    }

    if ( ! empty( $address[ $name . '_first_name' ] ) ) {
        $label .= $address[ $name . '_first_name' ];
    }
    if ( ! empty( $address[ $name . '_last_name' ] ) ) {
        if ( ! empty( $label ) ) {
            $label .= ' ';
        }
        $label .= $address[ $name . '_last_name' ];
    }
    if ( ! empty( $address[ $name . '_address_1' ] ) ) {
        if ( ! empty( $label ) ) {
            $label .= ', ';
        }
        $label .= $address[ $name . '_address_1' ];
    }
    
    
    if ( ! empty( $address[ $name . '_city' ] ) ) {
        if ( ! empty( $label ) ) {
            $label .= ', ';
        }
        $label .= $address[ $name . '_city' ];
    }
    if ( ! empty( $address[ $name . '_state' ] ) ) {
        if ( ! empty( $label ) ) {
            $label .= ', ';
        }
        $label .= $address[ $name . '_state' ];
    }

    return apply_filters( 'wc_address_book_address_select_label', $label, $address, $name );
}
```

Comment: This is part of the address book code to add a drop down menu at checkout

Comment: When I select a different address from the drop down there are no changes that happen in the readonly fields, but if i switch them back to normal or disabled fields they repopulate with the different address information.  Any idea why fields with a readonly attribute would not "refresh" when changing the selection.

Comment: I think I might have found the solution.  I added a function to remove all of the disabled attributes when clicking submit on the form.  Here it is:

Comment: $('form').submit(function(e) {
      $(':disabled').each(function(e) {
         $(this).removeAttr('disabled');